# How to use HTML5 <canvas> using particles

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5-canvas, particles

http://craftedbygc.com/ this is the URL and I want to use my own logo like this with HTML-canvas.

The URL using canvas particle but It is very difficult for me to get it done, can any one help me in understanding this, about how this can be achieved in HTML-canvas, is there any tool to create canvas code or something like this
Code I inspected from this site.

```
<div id="particle-slider">
 <div class="slides">
  <div class="slide" data-src="http://craftedbygc.com/wp-content/themes/craftedbygc/images/logo.png"></div>
 </div>
 <canvas class="draw" id="canvas-particle" width="1279" height="403"></canvas>
<canvas width="351" height="397" style="display: none;"></canvas><canvas style="display: none;"></canvas><canvas style="display: none;"></canvas><p></p></div>
```

Comment: Most of the time, canvas get painted thanks to javascript, you may find more interesting code in the script portions of the page.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, do we have some sort of editors or tools to create canvas?

Comment: Question asking to recommends tools or software are off-topic on SO. Also, any text-editor will help you create js files, and there are a lot of libraries helping canvas editing, did you searched before asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase the canvas particle by visiting this [link](http://particleslider.com/).